# How to vertically and horizontally center a P of text in the page

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page that justs has a paragraph of text centered in the page vertically and horizonally. Any ideas on how? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here is how: http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/vAdzu/

Answer (score 1):

If you know the paragraph width/height, you may use CSS with [this method](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/). I can only think of tables for dynamic content, maybe the CSS experts will have better options.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 30%;"></td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td style="width: 30%;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ajust the widths to your suiting. This is short of using complicated JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, won't let me post a table. <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 30%;"></td>
  <td>Test</td>
  <td style="width: 30%;"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>

Comment: I prefer to not use CSS for sites that just need a paragraph or such, actual projects or sites that require CSS anyway, I do tend to use negative margins. Never used jsFiddle though.