# Center text vertically in a div?

Tags: html, css

I just cannot seem to center text vertically in the center of my div.It keeps floating at the top. Here is my code:
CSS

```
.dialer{
background-image: url('http://v4m.mobi/php/fb/images/close.png'); 
background-repeat: none;  
width: 100; 
height: 40; 
margin: 0 auto;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 12px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
box-shadow: 0 12px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="dialer" align="center"><a href="http://v4m.mobi/php/fb/index.php"   
style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; 
margin-top: 20px;">Close App</a></div>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: You have `width: 100; 
height: 40;` you need some units here. px, em, % etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center text vertically with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714371/how-do-i-center-text-vertically-with-css) and many others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.dialer`.

You could also do `margin: auto auto;` as you have fixed values for your height and width. You'd need to specify a 'type' of value, though, such as `px`, `%`, or whatever suits your purposes.

You could also do relative positioning like this:

```
.dialer {
    ...
    position: relative;
    top: 47%;
}
```

Comment: This is the only cross browser multiline solution in CSS only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, tried everything you mentioned above, but it does not work. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "margin-top: 20px" from the a tag, and then use something like:

```
.dialer {
    ...
    height: 40px;
}

.dialer a {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

...but this only works if you know the text will fit on one line.

Comment: Thanks. this worked. But it seems like a non-official fix, one you wouldn't see on w3schools.com... why doesn't any of the other fixes, like vertical align:middle work? I added 'px' to my width and height and added vertical-align:middle, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PvVr6/4/
I've updated the fiddle so it will work with multiline content also.

```
.dialer{
       ... 
       width: 100px;
       height: 40px;
       ...
       vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .dialer a {
        display: inline-block;  
    }
```

Comment: check the update:  display: inline-block;  instead of line-height

Comment: Thank you for your answer. tried it, does not work for me...
As you can see in JSfiddle, it throws the text to the bottom of the div, not the vertical middle